# Regression coefficients in multinomial logistic regression model

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'd like to determine whether the outcome (recovered / dead / transfered to another department) is influenced by a person belonging to an age group. I have data of approx. 235 subjects. There are 5 different age groups and I set the reference level to be 41-50 years. By looking at data, one can see, that for group 41-50 the ratio between recovered / dead is equal to 16/3. For the age group 81+ the ratio is 36/58. But when I am doing a multinomial regression model in R (multinom()), I get weird results. For 81+ group I get a negative coefficient of -6.78, that means, that if a person belongs to 81+ group it has exp(-6.78) = 1.13e-03 chance to die compared to a person belonging to 41-50 group. The p-value is significant. As I understand the coefficients are computed as follows: `log(P(X = "dead"))/log(P(X = "recoverd")) = log(P(X = "age group = 81+"))/log(P(X = "age group = 41-50"))`. What am I doing wrong?